# Can't find where my file is when using adb (it seems to be there)

Tags: adb, file-management

I will try and keep this brief. I am "working" on trying to get the sidelights on a  custom 10" android display with sidelights (for meeting signage) to work.

I am just starting to try and follow the instructions the manufacturer gave me (pasted all that below). I seem to need a file called  LibledsetJni.so

Anyway! I connect to the panel using adb shell in root. If I am in root and I search like this:

> root@rk312x:/ # ls -laR | grep (and either) "libledsetJni.so", or "ledsetJni"
>   it comes up with
>   -rwxr-xr-x system system   13432 1979-12-31 11:42 libledsetJni.so

WHich makes me think this file is somewhere. However I cant find the path. If I go up from root to system and do the search again, it comes back with nothing. I have been working on this for over a day and I can't find this file anywhere!! Can someone please help?

Thanks

Dave the frustrated

Instructions from manufacturer on getting lights to work.

Controlling LED JNI User Guide There are two ways to import the JNI : 
1) Directly use our JNI, copy the Libledset.Jei.so file into libs\armeab, use the below codeand load the lib document. public native void setLedState(int led, int state);static{System.loadLibrary("ledsetJni");} Reminders: In System.loadLibrary(“ledsetJni”) should use ledsetJni and not libledsetJni.so Library document name should be: com.glorystar.ledtest, category name is: MainActivity. The set I/O use setLedState (int led, int state); led is 0 setting red, led = 1 setting green, state= 1 open, state=0close

2) Rewrite the JNI document. Put the reference JNI document copy to the project, note to revise theJava_com_glorystar_ledtest_MainActivity_setLedState in ledset.c . Use your own projectname and category name for exchange, NDK programming should be self- learnt, themethod is on number 1.

Comment: Have you tried `find . -type f -name libledsetJni.so`? That should give you the full path.

Comment: OMG, some Chinese manufacturers are worse when it comes to writing documentation.

Comment: Assuming you're using Windows OS, try to pull the whole device files in a directory  by launching cmd.exe and point yourself into this directory Ex: c:\mydevice, then launch : adb root & adb remount & adb pull / c:\mydevice

Comment: finally use Windows search option when the whole files are pulled from the device

Comment: Hi Izzy, the "find" option is not recognised. I tried that already. Only seems to like grep.

Comment: Hi Adbelhafid. Yes I am using a windows pc, I will try and do what you suggest on Monday. Thanks!

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui I tried your idea, and a few versions of this. For some reason I either got: "warning skipping special file" or "warning - stat failed for path" and eventually it just gave error Protocol fault. 
I did however get the files! I downloaded an explorer apk, and put it on the device, then I could search and find the files and copy them back to the usb. I don't understand why it has been so hard to get files from this device!
Thanks again